# $.ajax not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to execute php file inside jquery, but it is not working out. I don't post or get any values through ajax , just executing php file and should get success message.If I don't have ajax line code, `click` function working good. But If I have ajax code, `click` function doesn't work.

I have pasted the code below, I don't understand where it is going wrong.

**HTML file**

```
 <ul>
       <li id="logout"><a href="#" id="logout_nav">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</a></li>    
 </ul>
```

**script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#logout_nav").on("click",function(){
    alert("This is a logout nav");
    $.ajax({url: 'logout.php', success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
   });
 });
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["name"]) AND isset($_SESSION["email"])){
unset($_SESSION["name"]);
unset($_SESSION["email"]);
echo "logged_out";
}else{
    echo "no_sessions";
}

?>
```

Comment: you have a missing `});` in your JS code

Comment: I had missed it only in post. But that dint solve it

Comment: Do you get the first alert in the onclick handler?

Comment: No, because of ajax, first alert also dint work.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one instance of the .#logout_nav, and no multiple ids?

Comment: I had missed one closing curly brace `}` for success method that was the problem

Comment: Didn't you see that syntax error in the web console?

Comment: No, it dint show up :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

There is syntactical error in ajax:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#logout_nav").on("click",function(){
        alert("This is a logout nav");
        $.ajax({ url: 'logout.php', 
            success: function(data) { // add curly braces for success method
                alert(data); 
            }
        });
    });
}); // add braces here
</script>
```